# What determines the viewport (initial-scale) of a .txt document on mobile browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, zooming, viewport

I understand that *adding* [`<meta name="viewport" content="...">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) determines the layout on mobile browsers for HTML documents - but is there something (e.g. HTTP header) that tells the browser how to display documents such as plain text files?

Case in point, [Gmail's robots.txt](https://gmail.com/robots.txt) looks tiny, like a desktop website without a viewport meta tag:

[image]

On the other hand, [StackOverflow's robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) is displayed in a more mobile-friendly way on the same browser:

[image]

Is this standardized anywhere? Does Chrome have some undocumented heuristic to decide this?

Comment: FWIW, in mobile firefox they're both same. Just thinking out loud. I'm guessing chrome detects if there's an overflow in default zoom value, it switches to another zoom value. SO's robots.txt doesn't have any overflowing text but gmail's **Sitemap** line is a little bit long.

Comment: Okay scratch that overflowing line idea. It wraps in SO's robots.txt so it would wrap in gmail too if that idea was correct.

Comment: From some experimenting (tested on a desktop and setting the device to a iPhone 5S) it seems to be related to the the `white-space: pre-wrap;` css in combination with the content overflowing. Removing it makes the SO text tiny but adding it to the google robots doesn't do anything unless you make the text overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is nothing that tells the browser how to display documents such as plain text files.

For some reason Chrome (mobile) zooms only .txt files with more than 302 characters.
This seems to be true for other webkit browsers too.

Gmail's robots.txt is 128 characters long and Chrome doesn't zoom it.

Here are two almost identical files, in the same folder; the only difference is the number of characters stored.

301 characters long .txt file: 
http://tonttest.altervista.org/301byte.txt
[image: screenshot of 301 character long .txt file on Chrome mobile]

302 characters long .txt file: 
http://tonttest.altervista.org/302byte.txt
[image: screenshot of 302 character long .txt file on Chrome mobile]

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but I don't think it should be a comment either.

Some testing indicate that it's not related to HTTP headers but related to a zoom formula which uses character count and viewport width. Formula could **probably** be derived from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/). But I'm not up to that task.

A few findings about this "formula":

- Shows visible effect only when viewport `width <= 980`
- Starts working when `character count < 302`
- Firefox doesn't care about it.

I'm guessing this is actually a standard and Firefox didn't implement it because it's not **that** important. But I could be wrong, and it could be a non-standard Chrome thing.

Answer (score 0):

also, in html from personal experience i know that when programming or coding a website, you have to put more effort into actually coding it to make it fit nicely to a mobile screen and/or a computer screen/monitor. a quick google search would help you with that too.

in your case, it's possible that google didn't bother to put forth the effort into styling that page so that its more easily viewable on mobile devices, and figured that people aren't typically going to be going to that text file on the gmail website. and they may have also figured that if someone did want to or need to view it, they'd be doing something such as, but not limited to programming or coding.
and stack overflow decided to because its a website revolving around coding and programming.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question on *how* StackOverflow achieves this. It's a text file and I'm asking what mechanism determines the scale when there's no meta tags in it.

Comment: oh okay, gotcha! sorry about that!!

Answer (score -1):

On high dpi screens, pages with initial-scale=1 will effectively be zoomed by browsers. Their text will be smooth and crisp, but their bitmap images will probably not take advantage of the full screen resolution.

Comment: These are text files, I don't understand how `initial-scale` is determined?

Comment: inital scale is defined in the website code itself the viewport takes the size from the browser and initial scale aligns the text . different websites have different viewports thats why text renders differently

Comment: Can you show me where the two pages I link to define this?